# cannot write image to sdcard

Tags: terminal, sd-card

After every attempt when the process is finished I get an error saying my mac cannot read the card, when putting it in my cubieboard it says the card is damaged. So obviously something went wrong during the process on my mac.

However. The card isn't damaged. It's new and working for everything else and can be read and formatted just fine.

This is the line I use to "install" the image onto my sdcard

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=Cubian-base-r1-arm-a20.img of=/dev/rdisk1
```

According to all the guides I find out there I'm doing what I'm supposed to be doing, but it fails. Any help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sync
```

I forgot to run the command "sync" after :P

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=Cubian-base-r1-arm-a20.img of=/dev/rdisk1;sync
```

Also works perfectly